# search page different results

Tags: pages, search

I have custom post types and would like to display the different results based upon a users search meta.

I have three custom post types that are styled differently and want to return the search results based upon their respective styles, not the generic page link and excerpt that it currently shows. could I use is_search()?

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'bsq' ) ); ?>
    <?php
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'bsq' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase you 2nd sentence? Not sure I'm understanding the question.

Comment: Sorry, I have three custom post types that are styled differently and want to return the search results based upon their respective styles, not the generic page link and excerpt that it currently shows. could I use is_search() to query the $_GET search or is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is_search() is going to return TRUE on every search you perform, so that won't do what you need if I understand correctly. You'll have to use a post_type conditional tag. But it shouldn't be too difficult with something like

```
if (is_search()) {
if (get_post_type() == 'type_1') {
    //Do the right styling
} else if (get_post_type() == 'type_2') {
    //Do different styling
}//endif
}//endif
```

etc etc

Hopefully that's what you're looking for.

Comment: should I try with this in the search.php page or the content.php?

Answer (score 0):

Use post_class() function by Wordpress core. Read the documentation and you'll get there.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class